# T-sql Narrow down results where duplicates exist

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find a solution where i can limit my results on a table of data where duplicated ids are found.

Example sample of data:

```
ID   | Typeofstaff | Role
---------------------------------------  
779  |    2        |  284
779  |    5        |  276
1299 |    5        |  488
1299 |    2        |  322
627  |    4        |  456
627  |    4        |  476
898  |    5        |  321
999  |    3        |  567
1027 |   null      |  890
1027 |    2        |  891
```

If the [ID] is duplicated and they have a [Typeofstaff] = 2 then just show me the row with the [Typeofstaff] = 2 **else** show me the next highest number either 3, 4 or 5 in the [Typeofstaff] but not a duplicate [ID].

If the [ID] & [Typeofstaff] is duplicated then show me either one of the rows.

If no duplicates exist in the [ID] then display the row as normal.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using sql server or oracle?

Comment: @hogan tsql = SQL Server

Comment: @Hogan Sql Server 2012

Comment: @squillman - TSQL is used by more platforms than just SQL Server (Sybase).  However, some people will select the TSQL tag when they mean mysql or other platforms because... well... reasons.

Comment: @hogan Ah, I sit corrected!  Didn't realize that about Sybase.  And good point about others.

Comment: @squillman -- yep, they actually wrote it with Ashton-Tate you could see Ashton-Tate (C) on the product on older versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() to do this:

```
SELECT ID, Typeofstaff, Role,
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Typeofstaff, Role,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY COALESCE(TypeofStaff,1000) ASC) AS RN
) X
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: @SoupOfStars -- you're welcome, now give me some soup :D